# Team Foundation Server 2013 update 4 doesn't build .net 4.6.1 apps

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, .net-4.6.1

We have a build server with TFS 2013 update 4 and latest .net 4.6.1 framework installed. When I try to build an application that has a target framework of 4.6.1 is builds it with lots of warnings:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (983): The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

Looks like it doesn't see the latest framework binaries, how this can be fixed?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49978 usually the developer pack can help.

Comment: Thanks, I will try once Microsoft website works again.

Comment: Is the developer pack helpful? If you build your project locally on your build server, will you reproduce this issue?

Comment: Yes, it works. Sorry for a delayed answer.

Answer (score 3):

Install developer pack:

microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49978

Credit: @Lex Li

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work. I've installed it on our build server (running on Windows 2012 R2). Trying to use C# 6  string interpolation, build fails. Project targets 4.6.1 framework. Any additional packages to install?

Comment: Recently configured a new environment with TFS 2013. Had to install VS 2015. .net developer pack didn't work.